# How to derive from incomplete class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

I have 3 classes: `Context`, `A`, and `B`.

`B` should inherit from `A`, and should use `Context` and `A` in its methods.

`A` is an abstract class. `A` and `Context` dependent classes with forward declaration in headers.

Code in `Context`:

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

class A;

class Context {
    ...
    A* someMethod();

};
```

Code in `A`:

```
#pragma once
#include "Context.h"

class Context;

class A {
    ...
    Context* someOtherMethod();
    ...
};
```

This is working fine, but when I try to add class `B`, I get a lot of errors:

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

// class A; // with this definition also have errors

class B : public A {
    A* method(Context* context) { ... };
};
```

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A’

> error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to write class `B` in such a way that this problem disappears? The fact is that the program should have many classes that are inherited from class `A`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are using 1 file. So what should I include in B.h if Im using 3 files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have forward declarations, then you usually do not need to include the specified header.

`Context.h` should NOT include `A.h`, nor apparently should `A.h` include `Context.h`.

Since `B` actually uses the `A` class directly (you cannot derived from an incomplete class), it will need to include `A.h`.

Code in `Context`:

```
#pragma once

class A; //pointers do not require an include

class Context {
    ...
    A* someMethod();

};
```

Code in `A`:

```
#pragma once

class Context; //pointers do not require an include

class A {
    ...
    Context* someOtherMethod();
    ...
};
```

Code in `B`:

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h" //inheritance requires include

class B : public A {
    A* method(Context* context) { ... };
};
```

Comment: Add to this - when you have co-dependent headers, you're then having to include them from source files in a specific order to ensure that the full declaration of a class is pulled in as opposed to the forward declaration.... this should be avoided otherwise you spawn a total maintenance nightmare.

Comment: What should I include in B.h then? And why I should not include A.h in Context.h?

Comment: You don't need _both_ a forward declaration of a class _and_ a header file that contains its actual definition. If you need to forward declare the class because you have circular dependencies, you definitely don't want to include the actual `A.h` in the same file you forward-declare `class A;`.

Comment: @NathanPierson can you explain this moment please, why I don't need to include A.h in Context.h if I'm using forward declaration. How Context.h will know what is inside A then? And why then I should include Context.h in A.h with similar logic?

Comment: As written, `Context.h` doesn't _need_ to know what's inside `A.h`. `Context.cpp` probably does, to implement `someMethod`, but `Context.h` doesn't. The same logic applies for forward declaring `class Context;` instead of `#include "Context.h"` in `A.h`. `A.h` actually doesn't need a complete definition of `Context` to work.

Comment: @Evgeny: Context only has a _pointer_ to A, so it doesn't actually need to know what's inside of A.